# Разделить строку по два символа

Tags: java

Разбить строку на пары из двух символов. Если строка содержит нечетное количество символов, она должна заменить отсутствующий второй символ последней пары подчеркиванием ('_').

Пробовал такое решение но оно не проходит тесты

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StringSplit {
   public static List<String> solution(String s) {
       List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
       for(int i = 0;i < s.length()-1;i+=2){
           res.add(s.charAt(i) +String.valueOf(s.charAt(i+1)));
       }
       if(s.length()%2 != 0){
           res.add(s.charAt(s.length() - 1) + String.valueOf('_'));
       }
       return res;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ну выведи результат на экран и посмотри, что там

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Эникейщик qwerty -> [qw, er, ty] , qwert -> [qw, er, t_]

Comment: И какой тест не проходится?

Comment: @AlexRudenko не знаю, проблема в том что когда я сам проверяю все нормально но когда нажимаю тест на codewars написано `./src/test/java/SampleTest.java:13: error: no suitable method found for toString(List<String>)
       assertEquals("Should handle even string","[ab, cd, ef]", Arrays.toString(StringSplit.solution(s)));
                                                                      ^
    method Arrays.toString(long[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; List<String> cannot be converted to long[])`

Comment: Ошибки надо бы сразу добавлять в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, нужно возвращать не список строк, а массив, так как тест пытается преобразовать массив в строку `Arrays.toString(StringSplit.solution(s))`, для чего нужно изменить тип возвращаемого значения в методе и преобразовать список в массив:

```java
public static String[] solution(String s) {
// ...
    return res.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

---

Также можно предварительно дополнить входную строку символом `'_'` и воспользоваться регулярным выражением `(?<=\G.{2})` в методе `String::split`, где `{2}` определяет длину фрагмента строки после разбития:

```java
public static String[] solution(String s) {
    if (s.length() % 2 != 0) {
        s = s + "_";
    }
    
    return s.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
}
```